# Python named tuple and putting * while calling object constructor

Tags: python

I am new to Python. While reading some code, I come across what is equivalent of following:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> a=(10,20)
>>> Point(*a)
Point(x=10, y=20)
```

Here, I do not understand, what is the meaning of passing (*a) to object Point in the last line. I tried searching in the python documentation for "pass by reference", "pointers", "operator overloading" but could not find much.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Once and for all. What does the Star operator mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `*` in a function name is used to [unpack argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)